# How to obtain an item from HashSet depending on a condition in c#

Tags: c#, lambda, hashset

In c#, for List data structure, we can specify a condition as a lambda expression for finding single or multiple elements by List.Find(Predicate) or List.FindAll(Predicate) methods. Is there any way to do a similar operation with HashSet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want multiple results you can use `Where` method:

```
hash.Where(x => Predicate(x));
```

If you want a single result you can use the `FirstOrDefault` method

```
hash.FirstOrDefault(x => Predicate(x));
```

Comment: Or even `hash.Where(Predicate)`

Answer (score 1):

Since [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0) implements the [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-6.0) interface, you can use extension methods like [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0).

So:

```
var matches = yourHashSet.Where(item => predicate(item));
```

should work.